# Building a custom Google Sign-In button for login purpose

Tags: authentication, google-signin

Does any one know how to implement Google Sign-In button to login into the own website.
I am using local host.

https://localhost:8443/

I am facing the below error--

Error:- "Not a valid origin for the client: https://localhost:8443 has not been registered for client ID 247458862265-di55v7mhm4l4bto043aavspg7tql7on1.apps.googleusercontent.com. Please go to https://console.developers.google.com/ and register this origin for your project's client ID."

Error:- "idpiframe_initialization_failed"

It should be fetch the my google account and sucessfully login.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message states you need to go to google cloud console for your project and register

```
https://localhost:8443
```

as a javascript origin as I have done here on mine

[image]

This video may help as well [Google Oauth: error redirect_uri_mismatch the javascript origin Quick Fix.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V0-4LnHwFho)